# Jenkins Pipeline Build with Docker, Google Registry, and Google Auth Plugin

Tags: docker, jenkins-pipeline, google-container-registry

I'm building a Docker image using a Jenkins pipeline (using a pipeline script that was auto-generated by JHipster). I want to push my final docker image to the Google Container Registry.

Here's what I've done:

1. I've installed both the CloudBees Docker Custom Build Environment Plugin and the Google Container Registry Auth Plugin.
2. I've set up Google auth credentials in Jenkins following instructions over [here](https://medium.com/google-cloud/how-to-push-docker-image-to-google-container-registry-gcr-through-jenkins-job-52b9d5ce9f7f)
3. I've configured my build step to use the Google Registry tag format, like so: `docker.build('us.gcr.io/[my-project-id]/[my-artifact-id]', 'target/docker')`
4. I've referenced the id of my Google Auth credentials in my push step:

(Hm. Needs extra text line after bullets to format properly)

```
docker.withRegistry('https://us.gcr.io', '[my-credential-id]') {
    dockerImage.push 'latest'
}
```

But the build fails with:

```
ERROR: Could not find credentials matching [my-credential-id] 
Finished: FAILURE
```

I'm basically at the point of believing that these plugins don't work in a pipelines world, but I thought I'd ask if anyone has accomplished this and could give me some pointers.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Try prefixing your credentials id by "gcr:".

Your credential id would look like "gcr:[my-credential-id]".

Complete working example:

```
stage('Build image') {
  app = docker.build("[id-of-your-project-as-in-google-url]/[name-of-the-artifact]")
}
stage('Push image') {
  docker.withRegistry('https://eu.gcr.io', 'gcr:[credentials-id]') {
    app.push("${env.BUILD_NUMBER}")
    app.push("latest")
  }
}
```

Please note the name of the image. I was struggling with pushing of the image even with working credentials until I've named the image wit [id-of-your-project-as-in-google-url]/[name-of-the-artifact] notation.

*When you get a message that you need to enable the Google....... API, you probably got your [id-of-your-project-as-in-google-url] wrong.*

Images can now be successfully used with url of eu.gcr.io/[id-of-your-project-as-in-google-url]/[name-of-the-artifact]:47.

LZ

Comment: That's certainly helped. I'm no longer getting a "Could not find credentials" error, but I'm stuck on a `unauthorized: Not Authorized` error. Thanks for the pointer!

Comment: And moments after I wrote that comment, I tried clearing out everything from my `.docker/config.json` and that seems to have helped.

Comment: Couple of hours after writing my response I ended up with working solution. I've updated the answer to reflect the solution.

Comment: In the build stage, I use the three part name: "us.gcr.io/[project-name]/[artifact-name]". But if the two-part name works for you, great!

Comment: Regarding the "clearing out everything from my `.docker/config.json`" comment: I can get some weird behaviour if I mix-and-match the use of the trailing slash in `docker.withRegistry('https://us.gcr.io/', '[my-credential-id]')`. That seems to cause `.docker/config.json` to contain multiple references to the repo (some with trailing slashes and some without).

Comment: This gcr: prefix solution didn't work for me unfortunately. Jenkins Pipeline docs state that the credentials for docker.withRegistry should refer to Username Password credentials.

Comment: @u-phoria: the gcr: prefix assumes you have the Google Container Registry Auth plugin installed in your Jenkins server.

Comment: I also needed to install the **Google Container Registry Auth** plugin and use the gcr: prefix to make it work. For me it did NOT work in any other way.

Comment: Another note for beginners: the above Complete working example needs to be in a `node {}` block:  https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/#declarative-pipeline

Comment: I can't believe how many of these insights are missing from published documentation

Answer (score 1):

The previous answers didn't seem to work for me anymore. This is the syntax that works for me:

```
stage('Push Image') {
        steps {
            script {
                docker.withRegistry('https://gcr.io', 'gcr:my-credential-id') {
                    dockerImage.push()
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: For me even this step is not working. I am using the latest gcr plugins tough.

Answer (score 1):

Other way of setting up Google cloud registry can be as below where you use withCredentials plugin and use file credential type.

```
withCredentials([file(credentialsId: 'gcr-private-repo-reader', variable: 'GC_KEY')]){
                sh '''
                    chmod 600 $GC_KEY
                    cat $GC_KEY | docker login -u _json_key --password-stdin https://eu.gcr.io

                    docker ps
                    docker pull eu.gcr.io/<reponame>/<image>
                '''
                }
```

Answer (score 0):

check if you have https://plugins.jenkins.io/google-container-registry-auth/ plugin installed.

After plugin installed use `gcr:credential-id` synthax

Answer (score -2):

**The below answer didn't completely work before, and is apparently now deprecated.** I'm leaving the text here for historical reasons.

I've ultimately bypassed the problem by using a gcloud script stage in place of a docker pipeline stage, like so:

```
stage('publish gcloud') {
    sh "gcloud docker -- push us.gcr.io/[my-project-id]/[my-artifact-id]"
}
```

The gcloud command is able to find the auth credentials that are set up using a `gcloud init` on the command line of the Jenkins server.

Comment: I've seen the gcloud command come back with "Not Authorized" a coupl'a times. Perhaps the authorization times out?

Comment: Yeah, the gcloud command loses its authorization information fairly quickly. This isn't a viable on-going solution.

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38764193/google-cloud-jenkins-gcloud-push-access-denied) question suggests an alternative approach.

Comment: This is now deprecated in the newer gcloud.